# SQL data normalisation for Calendar entry

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, database-normalization

I am working on a project that needs calendar entries to create reminders for the users. I am storing the id, title, description, date, and time of each entry in a relational database.

Does it mess up data normalization by storing the start Date & Time together and end Date & time together or would it be best to separate them as so: startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime? As the first option would be more efficient in retrieving the events from the database to load on the front end.

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you show no research effort towards answering. [ask] [Help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you rely on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: DB "normalization" with no qualifiers doesn't mean anything in particular. Neither do "efficient" or "more efficient". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) PS How to best represent date+time is also a faq.

Comment: No, I am not asking you to do homework for me this is not homework. It is a real-life scenario for a project I am working on. It's widely understood relational database structure can vary depending on the scenario and need of the programmer or project and textbooks are not always the correct way to approach a problem. I merely asked for an opinion on the best plan forward for mine. What I learned about databases and how to apply them to each scenario is different. I wanted to ask people with more experience about the best approach. As a community that helps people, I thought that was the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My choice would always be to store date and time together in a `DATETIME` column. Makes it far easier to search time ranges.

There's one possible exception: calendar entries that repeat at the same time. But solving that general problem is notoriously hard and beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: At this moment in time, there is no need for repeat entries. i wanted also to avoid transitive dependency and figured storing they together would prevent this, thanks